# Upload file with original file permission using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to upload file to my server using python with the original file permission

I'm trying to use the following code:

```py
import os
import ftplib

ftp_session = ftplib.FTP()
connect_status = ftp_session.connect(host=target, port=port)
print(connect_status)

login_status = ftp_session.login(user=user, passwd=passwrd)
print(login_status)

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    transfer_staus = ftp_session.storbinary(f'STOR file.elf', f, blocksize=os.path.getsize(filename))
    print(transfer_staus)
```

The file upload to the server but without the original file permission, how can I solve it?

**EDIT:**

Original file permission means that in my host the file permission is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  56046 Oct 15 16:11 file.elf
```

And on the FTP server after the file upload:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  56046 Nov 3 13:19 file.elf
```

Comment: What do you mean by Original File Permission, Can you be more clear ?

Comment: @Enosjeba, got it, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `original_file_mode = os.stat(filename).st_mode` to get the file's mode, then send a `SITE CHMOD` command after you've uploaded the file.

```
ftp_session.sendcmd(f'SITE CHMOD {original_file_mode} file.elf')
```

Whether `SITE CHMOD` works depends on the receiving end.

Comment: I got `ftplib.error_perm: 500 'SITE': command not understood` error

Comment: Well, then the receiving end doesn't support that, I'd say...